# Can't wake up from external monitor plugged in

Tags: suspend

Actually, I suspect the computer is waking up but my external monitor won't display anything (it turns on the backlight but screen remains black).

I end up having to open the lid of the laptop for display to turn on, then I have to close lid again.

I'm using VGA port on a T430 thinkpad

Comment: Same behavior here on several different laptops, with external monitors connected via display port. The problem begins after the external monitor was disconnected for a moment. If it is continuously connected since boot the problem does not appear.